# Setting up a polymorphic association where associated tables have different primary key types (UUID and Integer)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have 5 tables which are all `likeable` by a `user`, and a `likes` table which records this.

The problem is one of the 5 tables uses `uuid` and not integer for their primary key. So I can't have a typical `likeable_id` & `likeable_type`

Is it possible to set up a polymorphic association that handles different primary key types?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up with is adding a `likeable_id_string` which stores any `uuid` primary key. I then override the getters and setters to do the following:

```
# Overriding getters and setters to handle multiple primary key types on
  # this polymorphic association ( String and Integer )

  # Setters
  def likeable=(value)
    if !value.nil? && value.id.is_a?(String)
      self[:likeable_id] = nil
      self[:likeable_id_string] = value.id
      self[:likeable_type] = value.class.name
    else
      self[:likeable_id_string] = nil
      super(value)
    end
  end

  # in case likeable_type and likeable_id are updated seperately. I believe
  # this is done in FE (rather than passing an object to .likeable)
  def likeable_id=(value)
    if !value.nil? && value.is_a?(String)
      self[:likeable_id] = nil
      self[:likeable_id_string] = value
    else
      self[:likeable_id_string] = nil
      super(value)
    end
  end

  # Getters
  def likeable
    if self.likeable_id
      return super
    elsif !self.likeable_type.nil?
      return self.likeable_type.constantize.find(likeable_id_string)
    else
      return nil
    end
  end
```

You would think that the `likeable=` setter isn't needed once I've overridden the `likeable_id=` .. but seems like it is. If anyone knows why I need both please let me know as it would seem logical that `likeable` delegates to `likeable_id` and `likeable_type`

I feel like there's a use case for this to be a Gem. Something I might do soon. Please get in touch if you would like to see this as a gem (or if you think that's a terrible idea)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your tables name, but here is an example for a join table

```
class CreateJoins < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :joins do |t|
      t.belongs_to :uuid_id_model, type: :uuid # you specify the type
      t.belongs_to :integer_id_model # you don't need anything
      t.index %i[uuid_id_model integer_id_model], unique: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I other words, specify on the columns that they are of type `uuid`

If you need to change a column type of your join tables, you can do like so :

```
class ChangeColumnType < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :some_join_table, :some_join_column, :uuid
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey Ben, not really the solution I was looking for. Instead I am overriding the getters and setters.

Comment: sorry i might have misunderstood; I based my answer on this 'Is it possible to set up a polymorphic association that handles different primary key types' / could you maybe expose quickly your workaround ?

Comment: I've just added it. What I was looking for is to use the polymorphic association as I normally would. Your solution is nice, but I don't really want a table for enabling an `int id` to reference a `UUID`. I don't think you misunderstood. You solution would also work, I just chose what I feel is a nicer solution (personal preference)

Comment: Ahh ok, I see the confusion. No, I didn't have any joining table (But I guess my question wasn't as clear as it should've been).